When is a first-order delay differential equation equivalent to a higher-order ordinary differential equation?
The proportional delay differential equation
$$
xf'(x)+2xf'(x/2)+C+4f(x/2)-5f(x)=0
$$
with initial condition $f(0)=C$ expresses that Simpson's rule exactly integrates $f$ over any interval $[0,x]$ and has solutions
$$
f(x) = c_3x^3+c_2x^2+c_1x+C
$$
for arbitrary $c_1,c_2,c_3$, as can easily be checked. These are of course the same solutions as the ODE
$$
f^{(4)}(x)=0
$$
which also needs three additional initial conditions on top of $f(0)=C$ to make the solution unique.
My question is: what is known about when a proportional delay differential equation
$$
\alpha(x,f(x),f(x/2)) f'(x) + \beta(x,f(x),f(x/2))f'(x/2)+\gamma(x,f(x),f(x/2))=0
$$
is equivalent to a higher-order (e.g. fourth-order) ODE, and how can one derive such equivalences?
